# Solve $(x^2 + 5)^2 - 15(x^2 + 5) + 54 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I got the square root of 14 and 11 but the answer book states that these answers are wrong. Can someone help me? I used this formula to find the individual roots

$x = -\frac{p}{2} \pm \sqrt{(\frac{p}{2})^2 - q}$

Comment: Try this: define a new variable z=x^2+5 and solve z^2-15z+54 using the quadratic formula. Then solve for x in terms of z.

Comment: OP please mark one of these answers right - it's good SE practice and people will answer you more often!

Answer (score 9):

Let $a = (x^2 + 5)$. Then $$(a-9)(a-6)=0$$

$$\implies a = 9\; or \;a = 6$$
$$\implies x^2+5 = 9 \; or \;6$$
$$\implies x = \pm\sqrt4\; or \pm\sqrt1$$
$$\implies x = \pm2\; or \pm1$$

This kind of equation is called a [biquadratic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Biquadratic_equations). Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Using middle term factor,  $$(x^2+5)^2-(9+6)(x^2+5)+6\cdot9=0$$

$$\implies (x^2+5)(x^2+5-9)-6(x^2+5-9)=0$$

$$\implies (x^2-4)(x^2-1)=0$$

$\implies x^2-1=0$ or $x^2-4=0$

Alternatively, using quadratic equation formula  for $x^2+5=\frac{15\pm\sqrt{15^2-4\cdot1\cdot 54}}{2\cdot1}=\frac{15\pm 3}2=9$ or $6$

Comment: I really know this is offtopic, but it's nice to see a Bengali here :)

Comment: @SohamChowdhury, where are you actually from?

Comment: I'm currently in 9th grade (in Bosco, if you know it) and I'm sitting in an apartment in Dum Dum :)

Comment: This answer has one-way implications. Presumably they should be two-way implications, i.e., logical equivalences; otherwise, you could be obtaining extraneous roots or numbers that are not roots at all.

Comment: @murray, not sure how the above method can introduce extraneous roots?

Comment: I wasn't objecting to the procedure, but to the manifest logic of its description. As I said, a write-up indicating that the answer you obtain consists of roots and only roots, you need "if and only if" connectives, not "if ... then" connectives. What you have (thrice) is the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

$(x^2 + 5)^2 - 15(x^2 + 5) + 54 = 0$

Let a = $(x^2+5)$ which gives us a simple quadratic trinomial of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0.$

$a^2-15a+54=0$

Factoring this we get:

$(a-9)(a-6)=0$

$a-9=0$

$a-6=0$

$\implies a=9$ or $a=6$

$x^2+5=9$

$x^2+5=6$

$\implies x = \pm2$ or $\pm 1$

You can check that these solutions are correct by simply plugging values back in to see if you get $0$.

$a^2-15a+54=0 \implies$ $(9)^2 - 15(9) + 54 = 0 \implies 81-135+54=0$